# Accessing the NSTableHeaderCell of a NSTableViewHeader for customization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell, nstableheaderview

According to the NSTableHeaderView class reference, an NSTableHeaderView uses an NSTableHeaderCell class to implement its user interface.

> NSTableHeaderView uses NSTableHeaderCell to implement its user interface.

[NSTableHeaderView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSTableHeaderView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000121-660)

Okay, so now I subclassed my NSTableHeaderCell and did the necessary changes but how do I assign my custom NSTableHeaderCell to an NSTableHeaderView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    
    @interface customHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell
    {
        
    }
    
    @end
    
    #import "customHeaderCell.h"
    
    @implementation customHeaderCell
    
    -(id)initTextCell:(NSString *)aString
    {
   if([aString isEqualToString:@"yourHeaderCell"])
{
    // do your stuff here;
}
        return [super initTextCell:aString];
    }
    
    @end
```

Now in other class wherever your table view you are using write the following the code:

```
    -(IBAction)addData:(id)sender
    {
        for (NSTableColumn *col in [tableView tableColumns])
        {
            customHeader=[[customHeaderCell alloc]initTextCell:[col identifier]];
                    
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I am new to cocoa dev and I did not get "Now in other class wherever your table view you are using write the following the code:-" I mean what is this addData. I did not understand how customeHeaderCell is being linked with with say my subclass of NSTableHeaderView? I still dont know how to link these two subclasses

Comment: The posted code makes no sense and does not answer the question.